Intriguing 80’s or 90’s movie with a female photographer and a kidnapping
I saw this on TNT ‘way back. The protagonist is a young female celebrity photographer, but as we learn more about her we find she’s pretty unscrupulous about the way she gets her photos. She hires a female assistant who is apparently captured and held for ransom. At one point the photographer receives a ransom note with a picture of her assistant being tortured/abused. But the ransom is a ruse and the assistant is actually working with her “captors” to defraud the photographer in some way.
A large life insurance policy on the photographer is part of the caper, but the plot backfires and somehow the photographer is able to benefit from their efforts by faking her own death and collecting the insurance money under an assumed identity. The last scene shows her calmly carrying her money to a plane that will apparently take her out of the country. Anybody know the movie title?

Sounds like Striking Poses with Shannen Doherty from 1999.

Wealthy [paparazzo] Gage Sullivan is arrested by FBI agents Linus Stahl and Valerie after burying blood-stained clothes. She explains it was all part of her endless efforts to get rid of a clever, persistent stalker. Gage hired charming security specialist Nick Love. He contracts the Major to turn her home into a fortress, gets her a new identity and identifies an ex-con contract murders suspect, whose aliases include Badger. After Gage's assistant Casey is kidnapped and probably killed, she hires Badger for revenge. This starts a series of discoveries, stings and dramatic twists.

Turns our her assistant and the other guys are con artists. It ends like you said (Gage fakes her death and ends up with all the money on a plane). Here are some clips from the film:



